# creating a model class

Tags: cocoa, model, instantiation

I've looked through the other questions and am still struggling so if anybody could take the time to look at this, it would be much appreciated :).

I currently have my app working fine but I've been reading and have decided it doesn't fit the MVC design pattern.  I am still learning lots about design and would like to edit it so that it is more sound.

I think I know what should go in to my model class, and I think that it should be instantiated in the app delegate.  My questions are: why in that location?  Is lazy instantiation the best/correct way to do this?  And finally, once initiated, do I use a property to access the class or do you use special methods?

Sorry for the overload; I am also trying to get my reputation up enough to vote on other questions! :)

Comment: How is your app structured at present?

Comment: I have all the arrays, dictionaries and strings within the viewcontroller and I believe that that shouldn't really be done.  I would like to have a model class that has the data in and that is then passed to the viewcontroller class somehow.  I think you have to create an instance of the class, bring in the header file when you want to use it, but I'm not 100% sure.  If you could give some guidance, I will give it some positive feedback and be forever grateful!!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to answer a general question like this, since there are so many ways one could implement any particular project.  In general, I don't think that instantiating a model class in your app delegate is necessarily the way to go.  Since a controller class mediates between the model and the view, it's often better to instantiate your model in a controller class -- for instance, I have a program that keeps track of the plants in my garden, and my controller class is a subclass of NSArrayController.  It seems to make sense to create new plant objects in the controller and then just add them to its arrangedObjects. I try to have as few connections (via properties or ivars) between classes as I can, the thought being that each class should take care of its own business as much as possible. Often, you don't need to have a reference to the class, because you are calling class methods to create new objects, and then those objects can access any instance methods of that class without any explicit reference to the class.

Comment: Thank you @rdelmar. So do you alloc and init in the controller class, then call the methods from there?  I've seen lazy instantiation tutorials online, is that a sound method to ensure creation of one object? Do you have to import the header file of the model in order to do all this? Sorry for the overload! :)

Comment: Yes, if you create new model objects with alloc inits in the controller class, then those objects can call any of their instance methods implemented in the model class.  I'm not sure what you mean by "ensuring the creation of one object", but I think lazy instantiation is a good idea for creating your model objects.  And, yes you would import the header file for your model class.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful.  All I meant was that if I alloc and init in one controller, then want to use that model again in another controller (for example), allocating again would probably be a bad thing?  Am I correct in thinking using lazy instantiation would ensure only one model created otherwise the 'created' one would be returned?  Apologies but as you can see from my rep, I'm very new at this and self taught :)

Comment: I'm not sure that lazy instantiation would insure only one model object when trying to access it across classes.  I think you would either have to have a reference to the instantiating class's property pointing to that model object (to test for its existence) or use a singleton class -- I haven't done much with singletons, but there is a lot of info on SO about that.

Comment: Thank you again for your assistance, I'm finding it an interesting discussion.  When I tried to access the model class yesterday, it worked well and I was able to get info from the model in to my tableview.  What I was finding though was that I had to alloc init the class in each method; I'm assuming that once the method ends, the object is released from memory?  Is this the correct way to do things or do you allocate and initialise somewhere else?  Is this the 'reference to the property pointing to that model object' that you discussed?  Do you have a sample code that I could refer?

Comment: In your controller, you should have a property that you assign your model instance to, so: in your .h file you would have "@property ModelClass *model;" and in your .m file you  would need the corresponding "@synthesize" directive and then in the implementation, self.model = [[ModelClass alloc]init]; Then, you can use self.model any time you need to reference that model object, and not have to alloc init it more than once.  You will also need an "@class ModelClass;" line above the @interface line in the .h file so the compiler knows about that class.